# selenium get blocked quickly by websites - SSL handshake error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, e2e-testing

I'm using selenium & selenium wire in my project.
I'm writing flows to log in to aws and gcp portals..
my flows works good but when I enter to aws/gcp portal I get an errors and I see blank page..

aws portal
link: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1#

[image]

gcp portal
[image]

selenium driver
`

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from seleniumwire.webdriver import ChromeOptions

def test_aws_flow():

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
    options.add_argument('--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process')
    options.add_argument("--ignore_ssl")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
    options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('disable-web-security')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('....any-hidden-url')
    # more flow actions - then it open aws portal
```

`

I found some issues in github into the library selenium wire that not worked for me..
https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/566

- they recommended to use with undetected bot chromedriver , I tried but it still show me the same issue.

***some updates***

I added openssl.cnf and run it locally in my test using pycharm

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

It success to log in into gcp and to aws..why is that? how can I be sure it will not not happen in prod environment when I deploy it to aws lambda?

Answer (score 0):

If your page does not open, please let me know. I believe they are
detecting bots. You might want to try using fake user agent as shown in
the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1#")
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
```

Note - please remove the extra code which you didn't need. Thank you..!

Comment: it didn't work.. I edited my post with some updated if you can see